# error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, dynamic-memory-allocation, lvalue

I'm getting a `C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value`  error on the line with 
`*shp[count]).area()=max;` and I'm not sure what that means. The shape class is a base class for all of the shapes and I'm trying to put them all in an array of type shape and find which one has the largest area

```
int largestArea()
{
float max =-99999;
int index = 0;
shape *shp[6];
shp[0 ]= new trapezoid (4,6,3);
shp[1 ]= new triangle  (4,2);
shp[2 ]= new parallelogram (3,8);
shp[3 ]= new trapezoid (2,6,3);
shp[4 ]= new triangle  (5,2);
shp[5 ]= new parallelogram (2,7);

for(int count=0;count<6;count++)
{
    if((*shp[count]).area()>=max)
    {
        (*shp[count]).area()=max;
        index = count;
    }
}

return index;
```

Comment: What does `area()` return?

Comment: That error says that you're trying to assign to something that is not assignable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930948/error-c2106-left-operand-must-be-l-value)

Comment: So, what is your intent with that `(*shp[count]).area()=max` assignment? What are you trying to do by this?

Comment: @Adam area() returns the shapes respective area in a float

Comment: @AndreyT im trying to get the value of the area in the array and make it that max but only if its larger then it

Comment: Well, if you want to update the current `max`, then it should be `max = (*shp[count]).area()`. Why did you do it the other way around?

Comment: @AndreyT just my mistake i haven't been programming too long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You meant to assign `max`.  Try this:

```
max = (*shp[count]).area();
```

Comment: haha wow im an idiot this is the second time i did this i think this may be the problem..... thanks a lot that was the problem

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm slightly off-topic.

Why don't you write this?

```
size_t index = 0; 
float max = (*shp[0]).area(); 

for(int count=1;count<6;count++)
{
    if((*shp[count]).area()>=max)
    {
        max = (*shp[count]).area();
        index = count;
    }
}
```

Reading things like:

```
float max =-99999;
```

is unpleasant.

Comment: Thanks for the tip will consider next time